# WCF service with gzip compression configuration (server/client)

Tags: wcf, compression, gzip, configuration-files

I got few questions regarding to gzip compression in my self hosted WCF service.

I implemented a custom gzip compression (using the msdn sample) and everything works o.k. (requests/responses are all well compressed).

currently the client config includes all the additional configurations for using the compression (bindingElementExtensions, policyImporters pointing the gzip encoder binary etc.).

Actually i thought that the client doesn't need any external configuration for using the service and only need to have "gzip" mentioned at the "Accept-Encoding" and "Content-Encoding"...
how do i configure my client to work that way ? i want my client to handle an encoded message if he gets one only...

Another question - is that possible to set a minimal size of message which the gzip compression will encode starting from that size only? the motivation is for optimizing the server's load and prevent a unneccessary compression of small messages.
or is it using the gzip compression or not using it at all?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Automatic decompression based on content-encoding should be built in feature in WCF 4 which is enabled by default.

Comment: yeah but when i'm removing the gzip configuration from the client and all its binding, i get an exception about missing extensions